# How to create an observer before save billing & shipping address on checkout page in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, php-5.4

how to show custom error message if billing/shipping(section) address is not valid .

or

How to create an observer before save billing & shipping address on checkout page in magento?

So for that I will fire an event.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the standard controller action events:  `'controller_action_predispatch_' . $this->getFullActionName()`

In the case of the `saveBilling` action the event is `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling`

and for saveShipping is `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveShiping`.

You can access the values sent to that action by

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
```

Comment: thank you now working, Now I have trigger a web message ins-ted of showing block. i think `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveShipping` inst-ed of `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveShiping' i'm right? any way thank you.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to add function using this observer

```
sales_order_place_before
```

When Customer click on place order this observer triggered before placing the order.

Hope this will helps:)

Comment: I want fire after filling billing address details. which event I should use?

Comment: **customer_address_save_before** use this.

Comment: I will come back after tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<events>
  <customer_address_save_before>
    <observers>
      <easylife_model_observer>
        <type>model</type>
        <class>Easylife_Validation_Model_Observer</class>
        <method>customAddressSa‌​veBefore</method>
      </easylife_model_observer>
    </observers>
  </customer_address_save_before>
</events>
```

sorry for correction. Now it's correct yesterday I post
 wrong?